# Magento 2 LayoutProcessor

Tags: checkout, custom, guest-checkout

**How to show the new field if the user is guest. 
If the user logged in dont show the custom field which been created.**

```
     public function process($result)
     {
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return;
        } else {
            $result = $this->getShippingFormFields($result);
            $result = $this->getBillingFormFields($result);
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

> I have tried doing this and I get Error code 500. Is there any way? I
>   could show the new field for guest users ONLY if not continue as
>   Normal.

**I have created a date picker in checkout page**

Comment: what is this custom field & where you want to show it?

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad i have updated my question

Comment: you know the place in the template where you are displaying it?

Comment: I havent touched phtml to show the field 
i have dont it through DI.XML 
<argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="guest_age_check" xsi:type="object">Module\PATH\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor</item>
            </argument>